# Which AWS product to use to run batch jobs?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a program written in C++11.  On the current input it takes too long to run.  Luckily, the data can be safely split into chunks for parallel processing, which makes it a good candidate for, say, a Map/Reduce service.

AWS EMR could be a possible solution.  However, since my code uses many modern libraries, it's quite a pain to compile it on the instances that are assigned for Apache Hadoop clusters.  For example, I want to use soci (not available at all), boost 1.58+ (1.53 is there), etc etc.  I also need a modern C++ compiler.

Obviously, all libraries and compilers can be manually upgraded (and the process scripted), but this sounds like a lot of manual work.  And what about slave nodes - will they get all the libraries?  Somehow I'm not sure.  And the whole process of initializing the environment can now take very long time - thus killing a lot of performance advantage that distributing the jobs was supposed to bring in to begin with.

On the other hand, I don't really need all the advanced functionality that Apache Hadoop provides.  And I don't want to set up a personal permanent cluster with my own installation of Hadoop or similar, because I will need to run the tasks only periodically and most of the time the servers will be idle, wasting money.

So, what would be the best product (or overall strategy) that could do the following:

- Grab the given binaries + set of input files
- Run the binaries on a predefined number of instances, using a recent Linux, ideally Ubuntu 15.10
- Put the resulting files in a predefined location (S3 bucket?)
- Shut everything down

I am sure I could write a number of scripts using the aws tool to achieve that manually, but I really don't want to reinvent the wheel.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly that would be pretty easy to script, and you'll need to probably use scripting to grab the latest code on the servers when they start up anyway. I would suggest looking into defining an AutoScaling group with scheduled scaling policies. Alternatively you could have a Lambda function scheduled to run and issue the API command to create your instances.

You could either have a startup script on the server AMI, or simply pass a user-data script when you create the instances, that pulls down the binaries and input files and runs the command. The final step of the script could be to copy results to S3 and shutdown the server.

Comment: So, basically, you don't know a product that would make my life easier here?  I've already started looking into aws cli, but was hopeful some of this was already automated.  I'll look into the AutoScaling stuff, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The (relatively new) [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) is made for this purpose specifically.

Comment: This particular project is in the past. At that time I did what I said I'd do - I wrote a script which automated the full process from compiling the binary to splitting the task into chunks and then creating the EC2 instances, pushing the binaries and work assignments, monitoring, generating the results and mailing the report.  Ended up with a non-trivial python script, but it worked pretty well.  Had a GUI interface for the convenience of the end users who were not very technical.